# Add double quotes to a list to display in a label

Tags: c#, asp.net

Morning folks,
I have an ASP.Net C# page that pulls in a list of servers from a SQL box and displays the list of servers in a label. ("srv1,srv2,srv3").  I need to add double quotes around each of the servers names. ("srv1","srv2","srv3",)

Any help would be greatly appreached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have string

```
string str = "srv1,srv2,srv3";
```

Then you can simply do

```
str = "\"" + str.Replace(",", "\",\"") + "\"";
```

Now `str` contains `"srv1","srv2","srv3"`

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!  I have been searching for about 3 days to find this answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you are trying to use double quotes in a string.
If you want to use such,

you can use escape character:

```
("\"srv1\",\"srv2\",\"srv3\"",)
```

for the sake of simplicity, you can even convert it to a function:

```
private string quoteString(string serverName){
   return "\"" + serverName + "\"";
}
```

Also, if you have already "srv1,srv2,srv3" format, find ',' characters in the string and add " before and after comma. Also, notice that you should add to first index and last index ".